# As you scroll highlight header

Tags: jquery, scroll, highlight

I have set the sessions into rows.

```
<div class="container" id="session1">
  <div class="row session">
    <div class="fourcol">
        <h2>Session 3:</h2>
    </div>

     <div class="fourcol last">
         <p> Information about session </p>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

I have many of these sessions and need a way to highlight that you are reading session 1. I would like to add a `.selected` class to `<h2 class="selected">Session 3:</h2>` as you scroll past it.

I'm hoping this will also add the `.selected` class if there are any incoming anchor links. to /sessions#session1 because it would have to 'scroll' to that position

Any help would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would recommend a look at [jQuery Waypoints](http://imakewebthings.github.com/jquery-waypoints/), it's got exactly what you're looking for, and it's easy to use.

[Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/J7ygT/2/) I made, where I add the `.selected` class when an element is scrolled into the viewport using jQuery Waypoints.

---

You can of course do it yourself as well, but you'd be doing the same thing Waypoint is already doing.
First use the [`.scroll` event](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/) on either document or a desired element to capture particular event you want.

```
$(document).scroll(function(e){
});
```

Then use [`.scrollTop`](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) to check where you are, and add "boundaries" your elements have to be within, based on the viewport, ie, the window.

```
$(document).scroll(function(e){
    var bound_top = $(this).scrollTop(),
        bound_bottom = bound_top + $(window).height();
});
```

Then check each header/section element to see if they are within those boundaries

```
$(document).scroll(function(e){
    var bound_top = $(this).scrollTop(),
        bound_bottom = bound_top + $(window).height();

    $("h2").each(function(){
        if( 
            $(this).position().top >= bound_top &&
            $(this).position().top + $(this).outerHeight() <= bound_bottom
        ){
            $(this).addClass("selected");
        }else{
            $(this).removeClass("selected");
        }
    }
});
```

It would look a little something like [in this example](http://jsfiddle.net/4kLmc/1/) I made.

This approach lets you do things exactly the way you want them.
jQuery Waypoints is a good and fast alternative.

Comment: Thanks so much ShadowScripter. I didn't know about waypoints, I wouldn't know how to implement either so thanks for showing me. Thanks again!